# Angular errors on prod mode that weren´t shown on dev mode

Tags: angular, deployment

I have an Angular app and when I run the command `ng serve --prod` appears a lot of errors that were not shown when I run `ng serve`.

Is this normal? How could I avoid this, because now I have to solve a lot of things I thought they were rigth.

Comment: can you post some of the errors

Comment: @Kardon63 Errors are related to wrong types and arguments expected in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're running angular <= 8, the --prod flag does an AOT build which is significantly stricter about template code than the JIT build used for dev mode.

Even in 9 and up, the --prod build is stricter.

The only way to avoid this is being super careful about making sure that template callbacks exactly match the controller signatures.  E.g. if the callback doesn't take a parameter, don't pass in one from the template, like $event.

Also, I run a prod build at the end of every day to catch any of these errors early and often.

Comment: Thank you. I undestand. I am running Angular 9. I take note of tour advice.